# Circuit to Decrement by One

Tags: digital-logic

How to decrement a bit by one? I have A and 1 . I want the result to be 'A-1' . How to draw the circuit?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How would you handle addition or any other subtraction?

Comment: What do you have to do to convert the ```0001``` into the ```0011``` instruction? (Hint, what value does ```B``` have to be?)

Comment: If you have already implemented addition, is there any way you could translate this operation into an addition?

Answer (score 1):

The decrement process can be derived using simple combinatorial logic design fundamentals. You start out by writing down the truth table of the inputs to outputs desired. Then for each bit of the results column a minimization process such as a Karnaugh map can be used to get the minimal equations for that bit.

Assume for example the number A was a 4-bit binary number then the truth table of the A to A-1 would be as shown below at the left. To the right is shown the Karnaugh map table for the low order result bit A'. Follow this same treatment for the other bit columns of the results to create three additional Karnaugh maps and derive the remaining equations.

[image]

There are plenty of web resources to read and learn the fundamentals of Karnaugh map usage thus I will not go into that here.

The hardware schematic follows directly from the logic equations using the appropriate AND and OR gates.